# Android java.IOException: Illegal Character in hostname at index 0

Tags: java, android

I wonder if anyone can help me on this. It's about android development.

i am using this image link for example.
http://soompi_images.s3.amazonaws.com/4b1d3d685350b3ee612d098fda7e7441_large.jpg

I get the image using inputstream to get the image content.

```
InputStream is = 
   (InputStream) new URL("http://soompi_images.s3.amazonaws.com/4b1d3d685350b3ee612d098fda7e7441_large.jpg")
    .openStream();
```

This is to get the image from the image link for my drawable.

However, i am getting Illegal Character at hostname at index 0.

I have tried htmlEncode but it does not work. So i hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The Java URL-class **cannot** parse hostnames with underscores in it, such as *soompi_images*
Pheonixblade9 is a really good work around.

Comment: how should i work around it? I tried changing the _ to ASCII code it also does not work.

Comment: The code below, posted by Pheonixblade9, works for me. Remove your code where you try to fetch the image and replace it with the code below.

Comment: The code work in the way that it does not show error because of the try and catch. However, the image still does not appear. I am looking for a way which i can get the image. Thanks anyway!

Comment: try stepping through the code.  That's part of being a developer, debugging code that works for them to try to work in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do:

```
private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) //
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try //
    {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
        in.close();
    } //
    catch (Exception ex) //
    {
        Logger.LogError("LoadImage", ex);
        return null;
    }
    return bitmap;
}

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException //
{
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    try //
    {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    } //
    catch (Exception ex) //
    {
        return null;
    }
    return inputStream;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't get the image with this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: what exactly isn't working about this?  It works great for me.  You do need to make sure you're doing this in the background, or it will freeze your app.

Comment: Yea it is running in the background. I mean i still can't get the image with it as i suppose is because of the underscore. However, i can't change the url as it is not by me.

Comment: What is the Exception being thrown by this?  It works just fine with underscores in my app.

Comment: The exception thrown is java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Then that's something wrong with your code.  The only exception my code should throw is MalformedURLException.  Step through your code and make sure you're passing in the URL String.

Comment: My app have 2 section. One of the section have the images retrieve. Only the 2nd section which get images from http://soompi_images.s3.amazonaws.com/??? cannot be retrieve. I am sure the URL string had been passed in since the 1st section have it's images retrieved.

Comment: If you're unwilling to step through the code to see if it works, then you may as well delete this question and try and figure it out yourself.  If you're asking me for help, please follow my instructions.

Comment: Yes. I am following. I did run the code. It's working on the first section but not the 2nd one. I am passing in the URL string.

Comment: Okay. Now i tried getting the exception at OpenHttpConnection. It throw out "Illegal Character in hostname at index 0" It says it this part "soompi_images.s3.amazonaws.com" guess it does not work for me. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = "http://soompi_images.s3.amazonaws.com/4b1d3d685350b3ee612d098fda7e7441_large.jpg";

url = url.replace("soompi_images.s3.amazonaws.com", "s3.amazonaws.com/soompi_images");

InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).openStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is to not use an invalid hostname in your URL.  You cannot count on any invalid hostnames working reliably.

> The Internet standards (Requests for Comments) for protocols mandate that component hostname labels may contain only the ASCII letters 'a' through 'z' (in a case-insensitive manner), the digits '0' through '9', and the hyphen ('-'). The original specification of hostnames in RFC 952, mandated that labels could not start with a digit or with a hyphen, and must not end with a hyphen. However, a subsequent specification (RFC 1123) permitted hostname labels to start with digits. No other symbols, punctuation characters, or white space are permitted.
>   <

Sources for what is a valid host name:

RFC 1123, RFC 952, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names)